# Having problems iterating through a list converted from .txt file

Tags: python, list, split

I am playing around with lists and am trying to come up with a list that has the nutrients from different food entries.

So I basically want to access one column at a time like this:

```
foodList = [["Liver" , 253, 0],["Spinach" , 844, 45],["Sausage" , 200, 100]] 
for x in foodList:
    printNow (x[0])
```

Which returns:

```
Liver
Spinach
Sausage
```

My list will be much larger than this and I need to open it from a txt file. The problem is when I try this by trying to convert the txt file into a list of the same format as above it seems to stop working. For testing purposes this is how I have entered that data in the .txt file.

```
Liver , 253, 0:
Spinach, 844, 45:
Sausage, 200, 100:
```

And this is the function of how I convert it into a list:

```
list = open('/Users/Danrex/Desktop/nutrientlist.txt', "rt")
read = list.read()
split = read.split("\n")
foodList = []
for x in split:
    foodList = foodList + [x.split(":")]
list.close()
for food in foodList:
    printNow (food[0])
```

When I do this code I return this:

```
Liver , 253, 0
Spinach, 844, 45
Sausage, 200, 100
```

But the lists are constructed the same except for the empty elements that appear when I convert it from the test file.

```
**Food List (not converted from txt, working)**
[["Liver" , 253, 0],["Spinach" , 844, 45],["Sausage" , 200, 100]]
**Food List printed once split from .txt file**
[['Liver , 253, 0', ''], ['Spinach, 844, 45', ''], ['Sausage, 200, 100', ''], ['']]
```

Can someone explain to me in simple terms what I am doing wrong here, and how to fix it? It would be greatly appreciated. Also, where did the empty elements come from, and how to I get rid of them?

Comment: You are not noticing that the lists are constructed differently.  `["Liver" , 253, 0]`  is not the same as `['Liver , 253, 0', '']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strip the `":\n"` first using `str.rstrip` and then split the line at `', '`:

Demo:

```
>>> strs = "Liver , 253, 0:\n"
>>> strs.rstrip(':\n').split(', ')
['Liver ', '253', '0']
```

Code:

```
#use `with` statement for handling file, it will close the file for you.
>>> with open('nutrientlist.txt') as f:
...     foodlist = []
...     for line in f:
            if line.strip():          #check if the line is empty or not
                spl = line.rstrip(':\n').split(', ') 
                spl[1:] = [int(x) for x in spl[1:]] # apply `int()` to all items except first one
...         foodlist.append(spl)                #append the list to foodlist 
...         
>>> foodlist
[['Liver ', 253, 0], ['Spinach', 844, 45], ['Sausage', 200, 100]]
```

Working version of your code:

```
f = open('abc')        # Never use `list` as a variable name
data  = f.read()
split = data.split("\n")
foodList = []
for x in split:
    if x.strip():      #check if the line is empty or not
       foodList.append( x.rstrip(':').split(', ') )
f.close()
print foodList
```

Comment: But I still don't know what I am doing wrong, or what you are doing to fix it?

Comment: @Danrex `[x.split(":")]` is wrong you need `[x.rstrip(':').split(', ')]`

Comment: So why when you split it at ',' does it not split it at every ',' as opposed to just in between lists? Does this make sense

Comment: @Danrex I am reading only one line at a time, it does splits at every `', '` but only for that particular line.

Comment: Oh one last thing. I seem to have blankspace at the end of the file. So the last list is empty space. I think it does this when it splits at \n. Any ideas on how to get rid of that?

Comment: @Danrex I've updated the solutions to handle the empty lines.